# How to get the whole text of StAX XMLEvent object?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am using StAX Iterator api to read an xml.

XML:

```
<FormData OID="QUAL">
    <IGData IGRepeatKey="1" IGOID="SQUAL" TType="Insert">
        <IData Value="0859" IOID="SID"></IData>
        <IData Value="DM" IOID="RDOMAIN"></IData>
    </IGData>
    <IGData IGRepeatKey="1" IGOID="SQUAL" TType="Insert">
        <IData Value="0860" IOID="SID"></IData>
        <IData Value="2013-01-03T02:00" IOID="QVAL"></IData>
    </IGData>
</FormData>
```

And Stax code:

```
while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
    eventString = xmlEvent.toString();
    if(xmlEvent.isStartElement() && eventString.contains("FormData") && eventString.contains("QUAL")){
        //do something
    }
```

}

It is working (eventString has whole text of xmlEvent) in my local environment.

But when i  deploy this into server, eventString contains like "Stax Event #1". So if condition is returning false.

I thought both are using different XMLEvent implementations. So i checked it through code, and jar is same in both environments: jre1.8.0_73/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.class

How to get the whole text of XMLEvent object? Am i doing anything wrong here? Please suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: There is nothing in the Stax API that specifies what toString should return. So you should never code against that. The actual implementation of Stax is chosen at runtime depending on many factors (system env, classloader ordering of jars which differs in JSE et JEE, presence of META-INF files...). You can read it up, but do not count on merely the same jars being present. You should read more about the XMLEvent API, follow a tutorial, it is NOT made for what you are doing here, e.g. starting at a given node, and printing the contents of that node. It's doable, but complex.

Comment: @GPI how can i read contents of the node?

Comment: @GPI why is it working in local environment? any idea

Comment: How to read : by iterating all the events that occur in between the statElement and endElement of your node. Why does it work in local : because the exact order of the jars in the classpath, the exact classloader you use locally, and the exact arguments/environment vars you launch your application with amount to the selection of an implementation that behaves in a way that is not mandatory per the Stax specification, and that you programmed assuming that it was. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#newFactory-java.lang.String-java.lang.ClassLoader-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every XML Event has 3 states

1. Start Element
2. is Characters
3. End Element

for eg if you need to access the data for " IGRepeatKey " from your xml file then in the state ( Start Element ), you need to check if IGData tag has started , if its true . Start a new Iterator which will iterate over all the tags i.e IGRepeatKey , IGOID , TType .

Try Something like this

```
Iterator<Attribute> iterator = element.getAttributes();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
  Attribute attribute = (Attribute)iterator.next();
  QName name = attribute.getName();
  String value = attribute.getValue();
  System.out.println(name+" + "+value);
}
```

Add this iterator in xml.isStartElement() block .